# nuxt link is updating route, but not changing contents

Tags: vue-router, nuxt.js

I am using nuxt version 2.8.1 for my website. Everything works fine, except nuxt-link on some pages.
I have a page, **/drinks** which is the listing page for *drinks* and **/drinks/{slug}** which is the *detail page*.

I first noticed the problem, in **/drinks**. None of the nuxt-link was working in that page. It got solved when I removed code that displays
validation error message from the form that is in separate component.

```
<span class='text-danger small'>{{ errors ? errors.first('name') : '' }}</span>
```

So, everything works on this page now. But, the *detail page* still has this problem. There is no components using validation in this page. No erros or warnings, in nuxt console, or browser console. Links just doesn't work. It updates the url, but, contents are not changed at all.

changing nuxt link to anchor tags works.

Another thing is, if I click any *drinks* in listing page to go to *detail page*, it works fine. Every link works. But, if I reload that page, or go to that *detail page* directly with URL, then *nuxt link* doesn't work.

I don't know, what is the problem exactly. How can, using *vee validation* in one component affect *nuxt link* in other components? And why is it not working?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the culprit finally. In case, anyone face similiar issue in future.
Vee Validate didn't support ssr, thus, it caused the problem with nuxt-link.
I am using another plugin **Vue Carousel** which doesn't support SSR as well.
So, wrapping carousel with  solved the issue.

And, another weird thing, using **v-html** with **p** tag also affected **nuxt-link**.

So, I removed all **p tags** with **v-html**, used **no-ssr** for components that does not support SSR and the issue is finally gone.

But, I still do not understand why nuxt link is affected and why there are no error messages.

Comment: Helped me a big time. Now I need to figure out all the places where I do not have ssr. How to do it?